# Проверка на `лицензионный ключ`

Tags: защита

Доброго времени суток.

Каким образом можно реализовать в PHP проверку на `лицензионный ключ`, **которую нельзя было бы вырезать из исходников**?

К примеру в файле конфигураци есть переменная $key = "6gx-00x-sff";
Затем в коде идет проверка, и, если $key имеет нужный формат, то работа скрипта продолжается, в противном случаи пишется ошибка.

Создание самой проверки не составит для меня труда.
Но вот как сделать так, чтобы её нельзя было вырезать? Для меня это большой вопрос.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: всякие ioncube , платно, недорого, не 100% защита.

Comment: @Essle, потому что стандартные примеры организации не применимы для PHP, это же скриптовой язык. Можете, в принципе, сделать свое расширение на C, куда всю свою бизнес-логику перенести, но это вариант для ленивых. По хорошему - это образ виртульной машины, запароленый конечно, который слушает по какому то адресу. И до нее можно достучатся только по нему. Все данные внутри неё. Ну а еще можно физический токен.